# Can't download pip mac

Tags: python, pip

I'm using a macbook and following these instructions https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

When I put `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` to install get-pip.py in terminal it returns the following:
[image: Result from terminal]

After that I put `python get-pip.py` in terminal and get this error:
`ERROR: This script does not work on Python 2.7 The minimum supported Python version is 3.6. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py instead.`

I don't understand this as I have Python 3.9.0 downloaded. When I try to check for if pip is installed with `pip --version` it says "command not found: pip".

Comment: Macs already have python 2 installed. If you installed python3, it will be accessible as `python3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the `python3` command, rather than `python`.